# Is it possible to populate a datamodel using a form and send it to the controller from Razorpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, model, razor-pages

What is the best way to fill the field of a datamodel instance using a form on a Razorpage?
Is it possible to instantiate and submit a model directly from the Razorpage, or do i have to read each individual field of the form and assign them to a model instance in the controller?

Currently i am doing something like this: (not my actual code)

In the view:

```
<form method="post" action="some_action">
   <input type="text" name="name" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost("some_action")]
Public IActionResult create_using_form()
{
  person p = new person();
  p.name = Request.Form["name"];
  /*do whatever with person, like save to a db*/
  return view();
}
```

I imagine there is a better solution, one where i dont have to populate every single field on my person object, one after the other. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to deal with each field in the form separately. Just use strongly typed view by defining the data model by using `@model`.

---

Let say you have data model class `DataModel`.

Then short way:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new DataModel());
}

[HttpPost("some_action")]
public IActionResult create_using_form(DataModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //...
    }
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

The [`Html.EditorForModel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) helper was developed in ASP.NET Framework MVC, but it still has implementation in the ASP.NET Core MVC. The `Html.EditorForModel()` returns an HTML input element for each property in the model.

```
@model DataModel 
<form method="post" action="some_action">
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```